# dropdown is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect the selected value to respective URL's.
but when I select any value it will redirect to specific URL but shows the same text as "My account" for any selected value.

How can I set the text dynamically on select?

**html**

```
<li style="margin:-3px 0 0 0;">
      <select id="myacc">
          <option value="1" id="myacc_link" ><a href="/Myaccount.asp">My account</a> </option>
          <option value="2" id="sign_btn" ><a href="/login.asp">Sign IN</a></option>
          <option value="3" id="out_btn" ><a href="/login.asp">Sign Out</a></option>
          <option value="4" id="o_btn" ><a href="/Myaccount.asp">Orders</a></option>
      </select>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    // bind change event to select
    $('#myacc').bind('change', function () {

        var op_val = $("#myacc option:selected").text();

        if (url == 1) { // require a URL
            window.location = 'http://xcome.sewuk.servertrust.com/Myaccount.asp'; // redirect

            var nval = "My account"
            $("#myacc option:selected").text(nval);



        } else if (url == 2) {
            window.location = 'http://xcome.sewuk.servertrust.com/login.asp';
            var nval = "Sign In"
            $("#myacc option:selected").text(nval);
            /* $("#sign_btn").text("Sign In"); */
        } else if (url == 3) {
            window.location = 'http://xcome.sewuk.servertrust.com/login.asp';


            $("#out_btn").text("Sign Out");

        } else if (url == 4) {
            window.location = 'http://xcome.sewuk.servertrust.com/ShoppingCart.asp';
            var url1 = $(this).text();

            $("#o_btn").text("Orders");

        }

        return false;
    });
```

Above is the code I am trying to implement but it's not working.

Comment: When redirecting to a new page or reloading the current page, all your fancy pancy stuff is lost, and the javascript start at the begin. To keep track of things across multiple pages you'll need a persistent storage, like cookies or local storage.

Comment: 1. change the bind to [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and 2. use [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) instead of multiple if-s.

Comment: define: `not working`

Comment: Where do you define `url`?  Also, any code that's after `window.location = ...` probably isn't going to do anything, since the page context is unloaded and a new one is loaded.  More to the point, what is it that you're actually trying to accomplish here?  Why are you trying to set the text of the `option`s to what appears to be the text they already have?  Why are you using integer values for the `option`s when it appears that you really want the URLs in the `a` elements within them?  Why are there even `a` elements in your `option`s?  That doesn't seem like valid HTML.

Answer (score -3):

Try to get the selected value by `$("option:selected").val()`